# Swift: Random SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple question about SpriteKit.

I created two SKSpriteNodes:

```
 let player1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player1")

  //    let player2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player2")
```

If i start the app, the app of course shows Player1.

Is there a way to do it randomly? 
So if i open the app, it should show randomly Player 1 or Player 2

I know that there is a way to do this with integers, like this:

```
 let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(7))
```

but how would i do it, with SKSpriteNodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want something trivial like this?!

```
let randomPlayerNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) + 1

let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player\(randomPlayerNumber)")
```

If there are two different image names:

```
let randomPlayerNameIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

let playerNames = ["playerRed", "playerBlue"]

let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: playerNames[randomPlayerNameIndex])
```

Comment: Is there also a other easier way? btw: what if my images are "playerRed" and "playerBlue"? How would i do this?

Comment: @zaph It's up to everyones, but I updated the code just for you :D

Comment: @iOSKoray https://github.com/thellimist/SwiftRandom/blob/master/Randoms.swift#L94
this extension could also help